# Sens impliqué de la réponse "je suis au courant"

Tags: sens, expressions

Le sens de "Je suis au courant *de* … ", par exemple "Je suis au courant de ce qu'hier il y eu du vent", m'est clair. Ma question concerne ce qu'*implique*, si c'est le cas, juste la réponse "Je suis au courant". Par exemple,

> — Hier, il a y eu du vent.
>   — Je suis au courant.

par opposition à, par exemple,

> — Hier, il a y eu du vent.
>   — Oui, je sais.

Comment: Using the “au courant” version in **this particular example about wind** could possibly be taken as a rather feeble attempt at humor, along the lines of the one about the inquisitive, soon-to-be executed (by electrocution) prisoner being told: “Calm down and have a seat, we’ll keep you up-to-date.”/ “Du calme, asseyez vous sur cette chaise, on va vous mettre au courant.”

Comment: @PapaPoule Re "On va vous mettre au courant"! Sublime---si j'ose dire.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"*Je suis au courant*" s'applique plus à un fait ou évènement, quelque chose qui nous concerne dans une certaine mesure, comme un ragot, un changement de planning, un ami qui est en couple, etc.

L'utiliser pour la météo a un sens de "*pas besoin de me le dire*", ou "*merci, j'avais remarqué*", un peu plus fort que "*je sais*".

"*Je sais*" exprime plus facilement l'indifférence, alors qu'avec "*je suis au courant*" on fait remarquer que c'était vraiment pas nécessaire de le préciser.

C'est mon interprétation, et j'aurais du mal à te faire la liste de ce qui est "naturel" avec "*je suis au courant*" et ce qui est plus sarcastique.

Answer (score 5):

Comme l'ont affirmé Mistalis et Louis GR, les deux réponses ont le même sens. Cependant, si l'on gratte un peu, 'je suis au courant' est plutôt employé lorsque la personne qui sait **a été informée** par quelqu'un d'autre. En d'autres termes, le premier dialogue peut suggérer que vous me disiez qu'il y avait eu du vent hier, mais que je le savais déjà grâce à un bon informateur. Il y a plutôt une question d'orgueil que d'impatience (j'ai de bons informateurs qui me disent tout). Ce n'est pas la seule explication, mais c'est la plus... courante.

A noter que, oralement, le ton jouera beaucoup plus que le sens. "Je sais" est plus "sec" que "je suis au courant" et peut donc être plus péremptoire.

Comment: +1. C'est la seule réponse qui remonte au sens de « courant  » on "a été informé"  indépendamment de sa volonté. Être "au courant" implique une circulation de l'information, on a été "branché" sur l'information.

Answer (score 3):

Dans ce cas là, les réponses "*Je sais*" et "*Je suis au courant*" ont le même sens. Les deux affirment que la personne connait déjà ce qui vient de lui être rapporté.

Comment: Je suis au courant. _Sémantiquement_, les deux ont effectivement le même sens. Néanmoins, dans la pratique, ils ne me paraissent pas interchangeables. Alors que "Je sais" est tout à fait neutre, "Je suis au courant" me semble trahir une certaine impatience avec le caractère "évident" de l'assertion. C'est ce que je voulais vérifier sans influencer les réponses mais "l'évidence" de l'assertion dans mon example était sans doute insuffisante.

Answer (score 0):

Dans ton exemple, les deux réponses ont exactement le même sens.
 *Oui, je sais.* reste cependant d'un usage plus familier : en fonction de l'interlocuteur, il peut être préférable de ne pas l'utiliser à l'écrit (lors d'un courriel professionnel, par exemple).

---

P.S. : *Je suis au courant de ce qu'hier il y eu du vent* me paraît peu naturel.
*Je suis au courant qu'il y eut du vent hier* est plus juste.

Comment: Le sens de "Je suis au courant _de_ … ", par exemple "Je suis au courant de ce qu'hier il y eu du vent", m'est clair.